# how to make download link in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

my controller:-

```
def download
    send_file( "/123.zip" )
  end
```

my download view:-

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

from where i am calling download option:-

```
<%= link_to 'download', :class => "btn btn-large btn-danger" do %>
```

please help me how to make that link..
right now this is showing error

```
Sent file /123.zip (1.0ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render :handlers => [:erb] instead. (called from c:in `find_template':)
  Rendered layouts/error/application.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.erb (13.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 60ms (Views: 50.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

Comment: could you paste your 'rake routes' command output?

Comment: i am new to it so do you mean by my routes?

  match "/PatientManagement/download" => 'current_inpatient#download'

Comment: open up your terminal, go to your project directory and then execute this command `rake routes`. this would list all the available paths in your project.

Comment: it is showing

$ rake routes
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.4. Using bundle exec may solve this.
C:/UP/devlopment/qmetrix/qMetrix-Performance-Reports-svn/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
C:/UP/devlopment/qmetrix/qMetrix-Performance-Reports-svn/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/UP/devlopment/qmetrix/qMetrix-Performance-Reports-svn/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your link like this:-

```
<%= link_to 'download', "/PatientManagement/download", :class => "btn btn-large btn-danger"%>
```

And in controller

```
send_file( "<absolute path to file/123.zip" )
```

You can also use Rails.root to get the Rails root dir.

Comment: hey thanks it is working now.. can you please tell me how can i add a alert box to ask want to continue downloading or not

Comment: <%= link_to 'download', "/PatientManagement/download", :class => "btn btn-large btn-danger", :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>   to add the alert box

Comment: i am really sorry for that but i am also new to stakoverflow i have 6 reputaion thats whay i am not able to vote.